# Calculating total votes with thumbs_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using thumbs_up gem for providing the user to vote on a post in my app. I want the user to vote both up and down and am following the instruction in thumbs_up wiki to get going.

Here is my vote up action in post controller :-

```
def vote_up
    begin
      current_user.vote(@post,:true)
      redirect_to [@topic.forum,@topic]
      flash[:success] = "You have voted successfully"
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
        redirect_to [@topic.forum,@topic]
        flash[:error] = "You have already voted for this one"
    end
end
```

when I click on the vote_up link, I get this error message :-

> cannot convert symbol into an integer

routes :-

```
resources :topics do
    resources :posts do
      member do
        post :vote_post_up
        post :vote_post_down
      end
    end
  end
```

view :-

```
<li> <%=link_to "Vote Up", vote_post_up_topic_post_path(@topic,post), :method => :post%></li>
```

What might be the problem here?

Comment: can you add some routes, so that we come to know what your `vote_up` link looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

judging from the error, and the documentation: https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up

change:

```
  current_user.vote(@post, :true)
```

to:

```
   current_user.vote(@post, {:direction => :up})
```

"cannot convert symbol into an integer" means that you are using a symbol ":true" where it is not supported.

Comment: thanks for looking into it but if I change it I get another error which says undefined method `[]' for true:TrueClass

Comment: ah, Sorry, try: current_user.vote(@post, {:direction => :up})

Comment: it gives my sql error :- Mysql2::Error: Column 'voteable_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `votes` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `vote`, `voteable_id`, `voteable_type`, `voter_id`, `voter_type`) VALUES ('2012-01-20 19:12:08', '2012-01-20 19:12:08', 1, NULL, NULL, 2, 'User')

Comment: is @post a valid instance of a Post object ?

Comment: yes @post is a valid object infact everything is working fine till I was using vote_for instead of vote

Comment: yes I have acts_as_voteable in my Post model and acts_as_voted in my user model

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6910/discussion-between-spotman-and-dev-r)